# Paypal transaction with different users

Tags: android, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am planning to create a mobile application, iOS and Android, I can make payments to other paypal users (using the SDK Paypal) all through the application. Some time ago (around two years or so, I knew there was no way)

**Situation:**

Each user will set up your paypal account when enter the app.
I am Gian user (user app), I have my paypal account and want to make a payment (consider any value) to another user of the app, Jack (who also have paypal account).
Soon after, I Gian, I want to make a payment to another user of the app, Smith.
And so on.

**I wonder if there is any way to do it this way or something else close it.**

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it by using the MPL library of paypal sdk
https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL

and documentation 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/
 hope it will fullfill your purpose